# Camel JPA Idempotent + OSGI (Jboss Fuse)

Tags: hibernate, jpa, apache-camel, osgi, jbossfuse

I'm have problem when i try to use JPA Idempotent in a Fuse Fabric OSGI container (fuse-karaf 6.3). 
I got this exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.proxy.HibernateProxy not found by org.apache.camel.camel-jpa [121]
```

I created a simple project with example: [camel-jpa-idempotent](https://github.com/renalexster/camel-jpa-idempotent)

## This is my route:

```
from("jpa:com.mycompany.model.Client?persistenceUnit=persistenceUnit&consumeDelete=false") 
                .split().simple("${body}") 
                        .idempotentConsumer(simple("${body.id}/${body.name}"), JpaMessageIdRepository.jpaMessageIdRepository("persistenceUnit", "ClientRepository")) 
                        .log("${body.name} processed");
```

========================================

## My context:

```
<osgix:cm-properties id="parametros.spring" persistent-id="parametros.spring">
        <prop key="db.driverClassName">org.postgresql.Driver</prop>
        <prop key="db.url">jdbc:postgresql://192.168.238.1:5432/camel-jpa 
                </prop>
        <prop key="db.username">camel-jpa</prop>
        <prop key="db.password">123456</prop>
    </osgix:cm-properties>
    <ctx:property-placeholder properties-ref="parametros.spring"/>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
                <property name="driverClassName" value="${db.driverClassName}" />
                <property name="url" value="${db.url}" />
                <property name="username" value="${db.username}" />
                <property name="password" value="${db.password}" />
        </bean>
    <bean class="com.mycompany.routes.CamelRoute" id="javaCamelRoute"/>
    <bean class="org.apache.camel.component.jpa.JpaComponent" id="jpa">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="jpaTxManager"/>
    </bean>
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" id="jpaTxManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistenceUnit"/>
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>

    <camelContext id="amq-example-context" 
        xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring" xmlns:order="http://com.mycompany/examples/order">
        <propertyPlaceholder id="properties" location="ref:parametros.spring"/>
        <routeBuilder ref="javaCamelRoute"/>
    </camelContext>
```

============================================================

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Bug confirmed and solved

The problem was confirmed as a Bug in Fuse 6.3 and was solved [here](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/ENTESB-6825), so i changed to use idempotent with camel-jdbc.